# Programmatically add image on category prestashop

Tags: import, prestashop

I'm trying to programmatically create categories with images in prestashop. I figured it out how to create category, but I can't find anything on adding images to categories.

Answer (score 1):

The category images are stored in img/ directory of PrestaShop under the following path:

```
/prestashop/img/c/
```

The image files in this folder are as follows (let's take example of a category with ID 3):

```
3.jpg
3-thumb.jpg
3-medium_default.jpg
3-category_default.jpg
```

You can simply add the images for your category with added category ID as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

we prepare code for synchronize with other software. Here you an example.

```
$object->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $nombre);
$object->link_rewrite = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => str2url($nombre));
$object->description =  array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $nombre);;
$object->meta_title = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $nombre);
$object->meta_description = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $nombre);
$object->meta_keywords = array ( (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => getMetaKeywords($nombre,2));

$object->id_parent = $parent;
$object->save();

$image = new Image();
if (!copyImg2($object->id, $image->id, $imagen, 'categories', true))
{
   $image->delete();
}



function copyImg2($id_entity, $id_image, $url, $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true) {
    $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
    $watermark_types = explode(',', Configuration::get('WATERMARK_TYPES'));
    switch ($entity) {
        default:
        case 'products':
            $image_obj = new Image($id_image);
            $path = $image_obj->getPathForCreation();
            break;
        case 'categories':
            $path = _PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
            break;
        case 'manufacturers':
            $path = _PS_MANU_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
            break;
        case 'suppliers':
            $path = _PS_SUPP_IMG_DIR_ . (int) $id_entity;
            break;
    }
    $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', trim($url));
    if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($url))
        return false;
        if (Tools::copy($url, $tmpfile)) {
            ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '.jpg');
            $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes($entity);
            if ($regenerate)
                foreach ($images_types as $image_type) {
                    ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '-' . stripslashes($image_type['name']) . '.jpg', $image_type['width'], $image_type['height']);
                    if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types))
                        Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity));
                }
        }
        else {
            unlink($tmpfile);
            return false;
        }
        unlink($tmpfile);
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating category, get the category's ID and create/upload or something a picture with name `'id_of_category'.jpg` and put it in root folder `/img/c/`.

Also make a copy of this picture and name it as `'id_of_category'-category_default.jpg` and make another smaller version wih name of  `'id_of_category'-medium_default.jpg`.

So if you create a category with ID 10, make 3 pictures.

Two high resolution pics (default prestashop uses 870x217 resolution)

```
10.jpg
10-category_default.jpg
```

One medium resolution (default prestashop uses 125x125 resolution)

```
10-medium_default.jpg
```

And put them all in folder `/img/c/`.

This will work with default prestashop theme/installation however to be fully compatible with backoffice settings for images (custom themes can have different suffixes for image names as well as height and width) have a look at `AdminCategoriesController.php` and it's method `postImage()` to see how the images are processed when you upload them through category settings in backoffice.

The main thing to look for is `ImageType::getImageTypes('categories');` which retrieves all info about category images settings and `ImageType::getFormatedName('medium');` for thumbnails info.